# iOS:Used type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') where arithmetic or pointer type is required

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, reactive-cocoa

When I use `ReactiveCocoa`,I want to observe my `tableView`'s frame, but there comes a issue:

```
__block CGRect tmp_rect;
[RACObserve(self, self.tableView.frame) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"%@",x);

    tmp_rect= (CGRect)x; // this line appear issue:
     'Used type 'CGRect' (aka 'struct CGRect') where arithmetic or pointer type is required'

    double width_radio = x.origin.x/[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    back_nav.alpha = 1 - width_radio;
}];
```

I don't know what this issue appear.

Comment: What is CGRext? Never heard of it.what is the result of the nslog.

Comment: I am so sorry about it, I have edited my question.

Comment: No worries.  What's the result of the nslog on the first line of the block?

Comment: @Fogmeister It logs:NSRect: {{152, 0}, {375, 667}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object x is an NSValue.

You need to unwrap the CGRect from it. You can't just cast it.

Try...

```
tmp_rect = [x CGRectValue];
```